# how to find ID of the control which is present in defualt.aspx in different page defualt2.aspx

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a web form which load 100 000 of data from the database.I Have 50 dropdown which is populated with respect to selectedindex change of dropdown .so to bind dropdown i am using ajax code .
I have written nearly about 200 line of ajax code in a separate js file.I am using 3 tier artitecture .I am not returning dataset from the bal class, am returning generic class to bind gridview.also i have created a class to bind the gridview.Also I am not using any update panel.

```
Is this approach will improve my performance.??
```

But there is a problem for me,i have to write code in js file to bind dropdown like this.

```
function GetAppStoreLnk(id) {               
           var txtnameid = document.getElementById(id);

           CreateXmlHttp();

           var requestUrl = "Default2.aspx?id="+txtnameid+"";

           if (XmlHttp) {
               XmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { getschemename(txtnameid) };
               XmlHttp.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
               XmlHttp.send(null);
           }
       }

       function getschemename(id)
       { 
           // To make sure receiving response data from server is completed
           if(XmlHttp.readyState == 4) {    
            // To make sure valid response is received from the server, 200 means response received is OK
            if(XmlHttp.status == 200) {         
                var strData = XmlHttp.responseText;
            if(strData != "") {            
                 var arrscheme = strData.split("|");
                     id.length = 0;     

                 for(i=0; i<arrscheme.length-1; i++) {
                    var strscheme = arrscheme[i];
                var arrschnm = strscheme.split("~");

                    id.options[i] = new Option();
                id.options[i].value = arrschnm[0];
                    id.options[i].text = arrschnm[1]; 
                 }      
            } else {
                    id.length = 0;
                id.options[0] = new Option(); 
                id.options[0].value = "";
                    id.options[0].text = "Scheme Name is not available";        
                }

                    document.body.style.cursor = "auto";    
            }
            else {
            id.length = 0;
            id.options[0] = new Option(); 
                    id.options[0].value = "";
            id.options[0].text = "server is not ready";
                document.body.style.cursor = "auto";        
            }
           } 
    }
```

but if i make class to bind the dropdown this will reduce my js file code line .How will i find the ID of the dropdown in the different page ie Default2.aspx .
Please help me .
How will i find the ID of the dropdown in the different page ie Default2.aspx .??Also i want dont want to use usercontrol or masterpage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question. You are trying to access the Asp.net drop down in page Default.aspx in the page Default2.aspx right?

Could you please clarify your requirement?

Comment: yes you are right.I am trying to access the Asp.net drop down in page Default.aspx in the page Default2.aspx .how will i do so?

Comment: Please use Session or Application State to keep the control